# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient parameter is required

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I am trying to Get my location  using the Google Play Services.I have added `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` in my gradle.Here is the code I am Using :

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.location.Location;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


public class TestActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    // LogCat tag
   // private static final String TAG = TestActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;


    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    // boolean flag to toggle periodic location updates
    private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    // Location updates intervals in sec
    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters

    // UI elements
    private TextView lblLocation;
    private Button btnShowLocation, btnStartLocationUpdates;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lblLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLocation);
        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
        btnStartLocationUpdates = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocationUpdates);

        // First we need to check availability of play services
        if (checkPlayServices()) {

            // Building the GoogleApi client
            buildGoogleApiClient();

            createLocationRequest();
        }

        // Show location button click listener
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                displayLocation();
            }
        });

        // Toggling the periodic location updates
        btnStartLocationUpdates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                togglePeriodicLocationUpdates();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        checkPlayServices();

        // Resuming the periodic location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    /**
     * Method to display the location on UI
     * */

    private void displayLocation() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {

            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }

        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            lblLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);

        } else {

            lblLocation
                    .setText("(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to toggle periodic location updates
     * */
    private void togglePeriodicLocationUpdates() {
        if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            // Changing the button text
            btnStartLocationUpdates
                    .setText(getString(R.string.btn_stop_location_updates));

            mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

            // Starting the location updates
            startLocationUpdates();

            Log.d("TAG ", "Periodic location updates started!");

        } else {
            // Changing the button text
            btnStartLocationUpdates
                    .setText(getString(R.string.btn_start_location_updates));

            mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

            // Stopping the location updates
            stopLocationUpdates();

            Log.d("TAG", "Periodic location updates stopped!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating google api client object
     * */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * Creating location request object
     * */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }

    /**
     * Method to verify google play services on the device
     * */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Starting the location updates
     * */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {

            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }

        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }

    /**
     * Stopping location updates
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    /**
     * Google api callback methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        // Once connected with google api, get the location
        displayLocation();

        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Assign the new location
        mLastLocation = location;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Displaying the new location on UI
        displayLocation();
    }

}
```

But from Logcat I am Having this error, Which makes no sense to me as I have called `buildGoogleApiClient();`before any Operation in my existing code. Please see my logcat output:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bourne.location/com.example.bourne.location.TestActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient parameter is required.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using your `mGoogleApiClient` before it is initialized.
The initialization of

```
private Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

should be done after you have initialized `mGoogleApiClient` in `onCreate`.

So change to

```
private Location mLastLocation;
```

and add

```
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

in your `onCreate` after `buildGoogleApiClient();`

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem. But it got solved by doing these following steps:

1. Add the following meta-data tag in the andriod manifest file, note google_play_services_version is given a value of 8487000

   `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>`
2. In app level build.gradle , add the following line in dependencies:

   `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'`

Comment: no. I have added this but the previous solution worked for me. It actually makes sense why it did not work before .